# How can I access files of an SMB share if I have the IP?

Tags: linux, smb

Having the IP, under Linux how can I access shared smb files?

When I type in for example:

smb://192.168.0.50 I get an error message.

Comment: In order to share files in this manner you need to setup a service called Samba on your Linux system. This is fairly easy to do, but a bit of a broad topic for a single question.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure the destination machine is running samba, you can pass an explicit IP to `smbclient` or `mount.cifs`:

```
smbclient //<samba_name>/<share> -I <machine ip to connect to>

mount -t cifs //<samba_name>/<share> <mount point> -o ip=<machine ip to connect to>
```

Comment: You can omit the `-I` option and just run `smbclient //<ip>/<share>`.

Comment: That "-I" was pretty mandatory in the olden days (when NetBios was a thing). But things had improved greatly since then. :-)

Comment: what's the `<mount point>`? Is that like a drive name?

Comment: It's a directory name on your file system where you want to see the remote files.

Answer (score 3):

```
smbclient -N -L YOUR_TARGET_IP
```

This will list all the shares in SMB service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a different **client max protocol** 
which can be done using **-m** tag.

just use the below command :-

```
smbclient //192.168.0.50/sharedFolderName/ -m SMB3
```